# Splitting a string into a pre-defined table in Lua

Tags: split, lua, lua-table

I am pretty new to Lua, so while my question is asking something specific, if you can provide an answer that provides the same result, please do so as it would be appreciated!

Basically I have a String and a Structure assigned with empty variables:

```
mystring = "Jon 21 Male Alive"

some_sort_of_structure { Name, Age, Gender, Status}
```

Basically I would like to somehow assign the four names to the variables in a structure and access them from the table by the variable name.

The string would be split by spaces and each value assigned based on their order. However, I cannot assign the variable by name. i.e.

```
some_sort_of_structure.Name = "Jon"
```

It would need to access the variable simply by where it is in the structure, i.e.

```
some_sort_of_structure[0] = "Jon" -- With [0] being Name
```

But afterwards I would need to be able to access it with some_sort_of_structure.Name

The main aim here though is to have a pre-set storage for a string and store that string correctly within the storage.

Comment: "*Table assigned with nil variables*" There's no such thing. What you've written is no different from an *empty* table. Furthermore, what is the criteria you want to use to divide up this string? How do you match a particular division up with a particular name in the table? Your algorithm doesn't seem very well thought out.

Comment: @NicolBolas Fair enough. I didn't know a variable defined in a table as nil didn't exist. As I said, new to LUA. The string would be divided by spaces, the matching is done simply by order, if it was an array (which may be a better option) I would want mytable[0] to be Jon, mytable[1] to be Jack and so on, but the idea is to make them accessible by a variable name without specific assignment, so I can basically fill in an empty structure with information from the string.

Comment: Split string to make table from it http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/lpeg.html and `for k,v in ipairs({'Name', 'Age', 'Gender', 'Status'}) do structure[v]=splitted[k] end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of your question, splitting a string into a table, can be done with this:

```
> function s2t (s)
>>     local t = {}
>>     for v in s:gmatch("(%w*)") do
>>         t[#t+1] = v
>>     end
>>     return t
>> end
> for k,v in pairs(s2t "Jon 21 Male Alive") do print(k,v) end 
1   Jon
2   21
3   Male
4   Alive
>
```

You can expand this to address the second part of your question with an `__index` metamethod.

```
> k2i = {Name = 1, Age = 2, Gender = 3, Status = 4}
> function s2t (s)
>>     local t = {}
>>     local function idx (table, key)
>>         return t[k2i[key]]
>>     end
>>     local mt = {__index = idx} 
>>     for v in s:gmatch("(%w*)") do
>>         t[#t+1] = v
>>     end
>>     return setmetatable(t,mt)
>> end
> mytable = s2t "Jon 21 Male Alive"
> for k,v in pairs(mytable) do print(k,v) end
1   Jon
2   21
3   Male
4   Alive
> mytable.Name
Jon
> mytable.Gender
Male
>
```

The `idx` function and metatable can be shared by all instances instead of being closed over ("upvalues"). Here's that version:

```
k2i = {Name = 1, Age = 2, Gender = 3, Status = 4}

kmt = {__index = function (table, key) return table[k2i[key]] end} 

function s2t (s)
    local t = {}
    for v in s:gmatch("(%w*)") do
        t[#t+1] = v
    end
    return setmetatable(t, kmt)
end
```